# SQL Server: is it possible to script table as UPDATE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I need to export/script two tables to my local database to a remote anyway.
Anyway I cannot export them as INSERT INTO scripts because I cannot drop them in the remote database and populate them again (because of FK and integrity constraints). So, is it possibile to script tables as UPDATE statements for each row, instead of INSERT INTO? I'm using SQL Server 2008/2012

Comment: Got any data examples?

Comment: Use SELECT columns INTO NewTable FROM oldTable.

Comment: Yes!! how should I post them?

Comment: @scsimon ehm, the old table should be updated from the new one, not by selects...those records already exist with their PK. Just some columns need to be updated

Comment: Ok I misunderstood your question then

Comment: You Can Make a Dynamically Query for Update

Comment: Do you know of the [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement, and would it be a help in your situation? That statement would allow you to insert new rows as well as update existing ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   ExtractTypeNum   INTEGER  NOT NULL --PRIMARY KEY 
  ,FileOrderNum     VARCHAR(11) 
  ,PrevFileOrderNum VARCHAR(11) 
  ,NextFileOrderNum VARCHAR(11)
  ,rownum1          INTEGER 
  ,Statusflag1      VARCHAR(9) 
);
INSERT INTO mytable(ExtractTypeNum,FileOrderNum,PrevFileOrderNum,NextFileOrderNum,rownum1,Statusflag1) 
VALUES (1,'2016-09-191',NULL,'2016-09-192',1,'IsInitial');
INSERT INTO mytable(ExtractTypeNum,FileOrderNum,PrevFileOrderNum,NextFileOrderNum,rownum1,Statusflag1) 
VALUES (2,'2016-09-192','2016-09-191','2016-09-201',2,NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(ExtractTypeNum,FileOrderNum,PrevFileOrderNum,NextFileOrderNum,rownum1,Statusflag1) 
VALUES (3,'2016-09-201','2016-09-192','2016-09-211',3,NULL);


select 'Update Table Xyz Set Abc='+Convert(varchar(25),rownum1)+' ' as X,*
from myTable
```

Comment: Here You Can See The Dynamic Query  Which will help you solving your issue

Comment: This looks interesting...I'm gonna have a trial but I'm not sure I'll make it because I've never seen anything similar before o_O. Thank you, it's really interesting!

Comment: @Lory LoryThanks buddy

Answer (score 1):

There is many ways to sync data between databases. As my experience, you can do by 2 main ways:

1. Using MERGE statement (it supports from mssql 2k8: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

   - write dynamic query to generate data script for 2 target tables:
     Select 'select * into #tmp from dbtarget.tbla where 1<0;' as data
     Union 
     Select 'insert into #tmp values(' + convert(varchar, cola) + ', ' + convert(varchar, colb) + ', ' + convert(varchar, colc) + ');' as data from dbsource.tbla;
   - run the query above at database source to get output script data.
   - apply script data to target database.
   - using MERGE statement to merge data between #tmp table and target table.
2. Utilize Log Shipping feature to sync data between databases in the same structure and in one domain network.
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190640(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've never used MERGE statement. I've tried to read some documentation and your example but I could not understand well...so, since I'm in a hurry I'll post my solution, even if it was more complex thank yours I imagine...

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to **Alfaiz Ahmed** this is my final working script:

```
select 'UPDATE ERGO.DBO.RESIDENZE SET CODISEDERESI='+CONVERT(varchar(50),CODISEDERESI)+
                              ',DESCRIRESIDE='+isnull(CONVERT(varchar(100),''''+replace(DESCRIRESIDE,'''','''''')+''''),'''''')+
                              ',INDIRIRESIDE='+isnull(CONVERT(varchar(100),''''+replace(INDIRIRESIDE,'''','''''')+''''),'''''')+
                              ',NOMERESIDENZ='+isnull(CONVERT(varchar(50),''''+replace(NOMERESIDENZ,'''','''''')+''''),'''''')+
                              ',VIARESIDENZA='+isnull(CONVERT(varchar(50),''''+replace(VIARESIDENZA,'''','''''')+''''),'''''')+
                              ',CAPRESIDENZA='+isnull(CONVERT(varchar(50),''''+CAPRESIDENZA+''''),'''''')+
                              ',CITTARESIDEN='+isnull(CONVERT(varchar(50),''''+replace(CITTARESIDEN,'''','''''')+''''),'''''')+
                              ',EMAILRESIDEN='+isnull(CONVERT(varchar(100),''''+EMAILRESIDEN+''''),'''''')+
                              ' WHERE CODICERESIDE='+CONVERT(varchar(50),CODICERESIDE)
from RESIDENZE
```

I had to use that `replace()` function because many Italian names have a single quote in their names so, for example, I wanted string `D'AZEGLIO` to become `D''AZEGLIO` in order to be correctly processed by SQL. Finally, before execute the query  I press `CTRL+SHIFT+F` to save the output to a sql file as a generated script.